# 2-column alignment in a Textview

Tags: android, textview, alignment, spacing

I've got a TextView in my app that will, on each line, have a label and then a data value. For instance, some line could look like:

```
Pressure (atm) 0.983
Acceleration 10.277
```

Now, I have a handful of data values at once, the labels all of various character lengths. I want to data values themselves to be spaced over a bit from the labels, and all lined up, like so:

```
Pressure (atm)   0.983
Acceleration     10.277
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience this is easier to do by separating value and label into two separate TextViews that you add to a LinearLayout for each row. And in the LinearLayout you can use layout weights  to distribute it how you like.

Comment: I have different layouts for various screen sizes and densities, that would be an extra pain to modify all of. Is there no good way to do this is a single textview?

Comment: use include.. and the included file would have the linearlayout.. trying to make a single textview work nicely will be more painful. I have tried..

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should add tabulator to the text.
The problem is how to add it in XML, because `\t` don't work. The solution is add `&#9;` that represents a tabulator.

For example in XML definition on Strings.xml

```
<string name="hello">Hello World, &#9;&#9; TesttabsActivity!</string>
```

In code you can also use the `\t` option:

```
TextView hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloTextView);
hello.setText("Hello\t\t\tWorld");
```

But this option don't align, only adds spaces (the XML solution also align)

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, I'm already using \t, as you can see here: testResult.append("\nTime (GMT)\t" + str); however this doesn't space them the way I want. It just spaces the data over from the label, but doesn't align

Comment: Is there a similar character for Newline.